# Unable to Connect to FTP Server hosted on my PC from another device

Tags: windows-10, ftp, android, filezilla

I set up FileZilla Server on my Windows 10, allowed it through the firewall. I can access it on browser and file explorer on the same machine. But I'm unable to access it on my phone which is on the same local network.
On my Connection Wizard, these are the configurations:

```
Connection type: FTP
Remote hostname: 192.168.137.1
Port number: 21
Authentication: Username and password
Username: ftpuser
```

I'm using Solid File Explorer on my android, and I receive the following error: `A problem occurred with network communication.` 
Nothing happens on the FileZilla log.
What could be the problem?

Comment: are you able to access other services on your LAN from your phone? It is not uncommon for Wifi to block connections to other devices on the LAN, in order to keep people from hacking each other in the coffee shop. if you think this might be the issue, look in your wifi config for a setting called Client Isolation, or something similar.

Comment: @FrankThomas Couldn't find it. Tried with mobile hotspot, still, nothing on FileZilla log but this time I get 'Connection Refused' error

Comment: However, setting up a server on Android and accessing it on PC has no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `ftp://` before the ip address.

```
Connection type: FTP
Remote hostname: ftp://192.168.137.1
Port number: 21
Authentication: Username and password
Username: ftpuser
```

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem?

Solid File Explorer defaults to [Passive mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Communication_and_data_transfer) FTP (under `"Set advanced?" -> "Yes" -> "Connection mode"` in the Connection Wizard), which requires at least two ports to work:

1. A control port (e.g. port `21`)
2. At least one data transfer port (e.g. port `20` or some other port range)

Based on some light testing, it seems likely one (or more) of these ports are being blocked, preventing Solid File Explorer from establishing a connection.

**Troubleshooting**

I might suggest looking at your Windows Firewall settings again, as well as any anti-virus program you may have that might include some kind of Wifi protection. You can try (temporarily) disabling these services entirely before attempting to establish an FTP connection to see if that makes a difference.

---

*Skipping Windows 10 Settings, you can disable the Windows Firewall completely for both Private and Public networks under `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall`.*

---

Technically, for `FileZilla Server.exe` and Passive mode, you should only need a single `Inbound` rule (looking at the `Advanced` settings for Windows Firewall). But it might be worthwhile to try applying it to both Private and Public networks if it isn't already.

If your Windows Firewall rules are for port ranges, they should likely be for ports `20` and `21` by default. Otherwise, they should be for the ports you are actually using for control and data transfer (set under FileZilla Server with `Options -> General settings` and `Options -> Passive Mode settings`).

**Other Possibilities**

- Theoretically, you may need to forward these same ports in your router to the correct host running FileZilla. Typically this is only necessary for accessing FileZilla from outside your local network, but...? If you do this, you should probably take a look at this [general guide to hardening FileZilla Server](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/49564.htm).
- FileZilla may be set to only accept connections from certain IPs. You can can look at this information under FileZilla Server's `Options -> General Settings -> IP bindings` and `Options -> General settings -> IP filter`. `IP bindings` defaults to `*` and `IP filter` defaults to empty fields (which should both allow general connections)